# Are logs in the LDF file being removed after a checkpoint?

Tags: sql-server, checkpoint

Using the `fn_dblog` I can get the active portion of the online transaction log of my database.

But after every checkpoint I can only see 2 entries showing the beginning of the checkpoint `LOP_BEGIN_CKPT` and the end of the checkpoint `LOP_END_CKPT`.

I'm wondering whether if the previous logs removed after every checkpoint or they are only ignored because the `dbi_checkptLSN` value that located in the bootpage indicate to the latest LSN?

If it is result of the `dbi_checkptLSN` am I able to move that indicator, and if yes how?

If not, and if the logs is not removed how can I access the previous logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transactions are not actually removed after a check point. Their state is only changed to inactive, so they are ignored by the `fn_dblog` function

Even when the transactions are in the inactive parts of the online transaction log, it doesn't mean that they are deleted from the LDF file

> "the VLF is marked as truncated (meaning the VLF can be overwritten
>   once the transaction log wraps"

[Understanding Logging and Recovery in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx)

An inactive VLF can and will be overwritten, but not immediately after the checkpoint, so the transactions will be there for a while. They will be gone when new transactions overwrite them. That can be in 5 minutes, or in 2 days. It depends on several factors

Please note that 'truncate' doesn't mean 'deleted', just marked so it can be reused, i.e. overwritten.

> When the checkpoint is performed, the inactive portion of the
>   transaction log is marked as reusable. Thereafter, the inactive
>   portion can be freed by log truncation. Truncation frees the inactive
>   virtual log files for reuse. Eventually, when a new record is written
>   to a freed virtual log, that virtual log file becomes active again.

[Transaction Log Truncation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> logs is not removed how can I access the previous logs?

Besides `DBCC log`, there are third party tools that read LDF files, such as [ApexSQL Log](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/read-a-sql-server-transaction-log/).

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Answer (score 6):

If your database is in simple recovery the log *might* be [truncated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) after a checkpoint.

This does not always occur though for reasons discussed in [Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (the most obvious being an open transaction)

To see the inactive portion of the log you can use the undocumented `DBCC log` command.

```
DBCC log(0,1) /*First parameter is database id with 0 as current DB*/
```

or trace flag 2537 in conjunction with `sys.fn_dblog`

```
DBCC TRACEON(2537)

SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
```

Of course there is no guarantee that the thing you are looking for will be there. It may be overwritten at any moment.

Comment: Another command that make use of a lot regarding the log is `DBCC LOGINFO` which shows all current VLFs.  Status 2 VLFs are still active and waiting to be truncated.